# jQuery scroll jumps to embedded videos in horizontal scrolling website on Firefox

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling, adobe-captivate

I've created a horizontal scrolling site that navigates using jQuery. It works fine in Chrome and Safari. However, when I use Firefox, the site jumps to the page before a page with Captivate videos embedded in iframes. When I remove the iframe or change the iframe URL, everything works fine.

Any ideas what could be causing this? Could jQuery be jumping to the top-most element in Firefox perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

May or may not be the answer in your case, but Captivate's standard embed code tries to focus() the SWF. This could cause a long page to jump to the section containing the Captivate SWF.

Remove the focus() commands in the Captivate files and see if it helps.